# Vue Checkbox groups toggling elements

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have some awkward data that needs a list of checkboxes to toggle whether corresponding elements are shown or not. I can't figure out a v-model or computed property that accomplishes that.

If there is no other option, you can add values to the data. Like a `isShown` boolean, but otherwise the data should remain unchanged.

You're my only hope.

[image: Edit jolly-gagarin-8ej3th]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my [solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-tristan-km44cv)

I used v-model assigned to a new `val` property on each item of the `elementGroups` array and combined with @change events to toggle groups of checkboxes together.  Displaying the related boxes was done with `v-if` and a method that returned the true/false value of the checkbox with matching id.